# Python flask deploy on vercel

Tags: python, flask, vercel

Hi I am a beginner of vercel.

I've tried many times to deploy my project on vercel,
It's fine if i didn't import the function in "basic" and "service",but i kept getting this error.

```
status code:500
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

I also have changed the file path from api/app.py to ./app.py, it dosen't work.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

from events.basic import *
from events.service import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"
```

The folder struture is as below

```
.
├── api
│   └── app.py
├── events
│   ├── basic.py
│   └── service.py
├── requirements.txt
└── vercel.json
```

vercel.json

```
 {
     "builds": [
         {
             "src": "api/app.py",
             "use": "@vercel/python"
         }
     ],
     "routes": [
         {
             "src": "/(.*)",
             "dest": "api/app.py"
         }
     ]
 }
```

I expect that it can import function correctly without throw me this error